# C# MVC App Double Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

My issue is how to handle 2 separate logins in the same application. I have an azure login set up and functioning fine, using `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` blocks to make sure the user only sees very basic stuff before logging in. The issue is that my website needs users to login again. It isn't a true login as we only need an ID so we can check if they are punched in (we can't have people working off the clock). After giving the ID, we check the punch status, and the return value gives enough info to figure out if they should be allowed in and what specific parts they should see. I'm new to MVC so I'm not sure what the best practice is when it comes to passing this status around the website.

Comment: `my website needs users to login again` This sounds like a design issue. You should know the user ID from Azure authentication alone. If you don't, then a design change is required.

Comment: It is 2 seperate systems. My company has azure integrated accounts but the accounts do not track whether employees are punched in or not. We have a different system that tracks punch in, punch out, hours, etc. 2 logins was a poor choice of words.